# How would I move the finished to-do to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I need help with moving my finished todo to a "finished list" instead of the del-tag using html to overline the finished todo. Anyone have a clue on how I should do this?

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import UserContext from '../UserContext'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Home() {
  const userInfo = useContext(UserContext)
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/todos", {withCredentials: true})
    .then(response => {
      setTodos(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  if(!userInfo.username) {
    return "Login to list todos"
  }

  function addTodo() {
    axios.put("http://localhost:3001/todos", {text: inputValue}, {withCredentials: true})
    .then(response => {
      setTodos([...todos, response.data])
      setInputValue("")
    })
  }

  function updateTodo(todo) {
    const data = {id: todo._id, isDone: !todo.isDone}
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/todos', data, {withCredentials: true})
      .then(() => {
        const newTodos = todos.map(t => {
          if (t._id === todo._id) {
            t.isDone = !t.isDone;
          }
          return t
        })
        setTodos([...newTodos])
      })
  }

  return <div>
  <form onSubmit={e => addTodo(e)}>
    <input placeholder={'What do you want to do?'}
           value={inputValue}
           onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
  </form>
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo => (
      <li>
        <input type={"checkbox"} 
               checked={todo.isDone} 
               onClick={() => updateTodo(todo)}
        />
        {todo.isDone ? <del>{todo.text}</del> : todo.text} 
        <p>Created at: {todo.createdAt}</p>
      </li>
    ))}

  </ul>
</div>

}
```

I was thinking maybe I should add something like this:

```
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
```

But how can I change the onClick function so it moves to the completed list, and vice versa, how can I change it back from completed list to the uncompleted?

This is my Todo model in backend:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isDone: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, {timestamps: true});

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Create the second list with finished todos, then make interaction with arrays of actual and finished todos

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, I hope it will help you

```
const [completedTodos, setCompletedTodos] = useState([]);
const [uncompletedTodos, setUncompletedTodos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(todos.length){
        let tempCompletedTodos = todos.filter(item => item.isDone)
        let tempUncompletedTodos = todos.filter(item => !item.isDone)

        setCompletedTodos(tempCompletedTodos);
        setUncompletedTodos(tempUncompletedTodos);
    }
  }, [todos])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter in JSX too and without creating a new list. It would be:

```
<h1>To-do</h1>
<ul>
    {todos.filter(i => !i.isDone).map(todo => (
      <li>
        <input type={"checkbox"} 
              checked={todo.isDone} 
              onClick={() => updateTodo(todo)}
        />
        {todo.text}
        <p>Created at: {todo.createdAt}</p>
      </li>
    ))}
</ul>

<h1>Finished</h1>
<ul>
    {todos.filter(i => i.isDone).map(todo => (
      <li>
        <input type={"checkbox"} 
              checked={todo.isDone} 
              onClick={() => updateTodo(todo)}
        />
        {todo.text} 
        <p>Created at: {todo.createdAt}</p>
      </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

You can try here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-ives-coc85e?file=/src/App.js